# Get the objects with the maximum value for a specific property from a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Beam` objects. Each `Beam` class has `X`, `Y` properties for coordinates and it also has a `Height` property.

Now here is my initial list:

```
List1 = {beam1, beam2, beam3, beam4}

beam1 = {X = 0, Y = 0, Height = 40}
beam2 = {X = 200, Y = 0, Height = 40}
beam3 = {X = 200, Y = 0, Height = 60}
beam4 = {X = 400, Y = 0, Height = 40}
```

As you can see **beam2** and **beam3** are at the same point, I want a list where I only have the beam with the maximum `Height` at each distinct point.

So the final list using `LINQ` would be:

```
 List2 = {beam1, beam3, beam4}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to group them based on `X` and `Y` and select the item with the maximum Height from each group:

```
beams.GroupBy(b => new { b.X, b.Y })
 .Select(g => g.First(x => x.Heigth == g.Max(h => h.Height)))
 .ToList();
```

Personally I would use [`MaxBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) method to get the beam with max. Height:

```
beams.GroupBy(b => new { b.X, b.Y })
 .Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x.Heigth))
 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
var query = List1.GroupBy(x => new { x.X, x.Y }).Select(x => x.First(y => y.Height == x.Max(z => z.Height)));
```

Comment: Max returns the maximum height, not the element that has the max. height.

Comment: @Selman22 - Yup Corrected! I was fetching the max height in each group, But now it's same as yours :P